# How to display grouped picklist values as one in dashboards

Tags: reporting, formula-field, dashboard

I am facing difficulty calculating two different picklists seperately for an object. For example, if an organisation object identifies both civil society and education as thematic area picklist, it is currently being counted as “Civil society and education” instead of counting as 1 for civil society and 1 for education.

Please see the screenshot.

Can we show 2 different counts for each civil society and education seperately using formulae fields on the object

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this with multi-select picklists. You'd need to redesign your data model and create a related "thematic area" object that would have an individual record per interest.

Here is a help article that shows how you can use INCLUDES in a formula to check if a particular value is in the picklist, but it won't solve your need. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004482&type=1